# Apache Reverse Proxy not redirecting URL with special charcaters

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, reverse-proxy, kibana, mod-proxy

I have set up a reverse proxy using apache mod_proxy, and it is working fine for all the URLs I set up, except some URLs which contain special characters (specifically *)
 I tried encoding the special characters, as well as using the nocanon flag. But none seems to work. I'm basically trying to run kibana behind a RP, and need to eliminate/replace the special character (use , instead of *) used by Kibana to query elasticsearch. Below is my reverse proxy configuration -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off

# works fine
ProxyPass /kibana http://10.19.225.20:5601/app/kibana
ProxyPassReverse /kibana http://10.19.225.20:5601/app/kibana

# works fine
ProxyPass /elasticsearch http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch
ProxyPassReverse /elasticsearch http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch

# Doesn't work
#ProxyPass /elasticsearch/.kibana/_mapping/*/field/_source http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch/%2Ekibana/%5Fmapping/%2A/
#ProxyPassReverse /elasticsearch/.kibana/_mapping/*/field/_source http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch/%2Ekibana/%5Fmapping/%2A/

# Doesn't work
#ProxyPass /elasticsearch/%2Ekibana/%5Fmapping/%2A/ http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch/%2Ekibana/%5Fmapping/index-pattern%2Csearch%2Cconfig/ nocanon
#ProxyPassReverse /elasticsearch/%2Ekibana/%5Fmapping/%2A/ http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch/%2Ekibana/%5Fmapping/index-pattern%2Csearch%2Cconfig/

# Doesn't work, just a test to use , char in target
#ProxyPass /elasticsearch/.kibana/index-pattern http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch/.kibana,kib2/index-pattern nocanon
#ProxyPassReverse /elasticsearch/.kibana/index-pattern http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch/.kibana,kib2/index-pattern

#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^/index-pattern /_search?fields=

# Doesn't work
ProxyPass /elasticsearch/kibana/%5Fmapping/%2A http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch/kibana/%5Fmapping/index%2Dpattern%2Csearch%2Cconfig nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /elasticsearch/kibana/%5Fmapping/%2A http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch/kibana/%5Fmapping/index%2Dpattern%2Csearch%2Cconfig

# Doesn't work
#ProxyPass /elasticsearch/.kibana/_mapping/* http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch/.kibana/_mapping/index-pattern,search,config
#ProxyPassReverse /elasticsearch/.kibana/_mapping/* http://10.19.225.20:5601/elasticsearch/.kibana/_mapping/index-pattern,search,config

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the commented lines, are the various things I tried but none seems to be working. Specifically I'm trying to replace the URL '[http://10.19.225.20/elasticsearch/kibana/_mapping/*/field/*source?*=some_number](http://10.19.225.20/elasticsearch/kibana/_mapping/*/field/_source?_=some_number)' generated by Kibana with [http://10.19.225.20/elasticsearch/.kibana/_mapping/index-pattern,search,config/field/*source?*=some_number](http://10.19.225.20/elasticsearch/.kibana/_mapping/index-pattern,search,config/field/_source?_=some_number) 
 I think I need some URL Rewrite Rule, in addition with RP configuration, but not sure how to do it as I haven't used Rewrite Rules before.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `ProxyPassMatch` with PCRE instead? As in `ProxyPassMatch ^/elasticsearch/.kibana/_mapping/[^/]+/field/_source yada yada yada`

Comment: From apache docs: The configured `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassMatch` rules are checked in the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins. So usually you should sort conflicting `ProxyPass` rules starting with the longest URLs first. Otherwise, later rules for longer URLS will be hidden by any earlier rule which uses a leading substring of the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.. another question in my mind is regarding the encoding of special characters, do I need to encode any special characters in the URL like * with 2A, _ by %2F etc ? And what about the query string (?_=23948798).. does it have any effect on redirection ?